# Replace vanilla js with typescript in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Currently, I'm using vaniall js with react. For the type checks, i'm defining the types in a separate folder called **types**. With this i can get code suggestion in vs code. However there are 2 problem i'm still facing with it:

1. Auto Import does not work with this.
2. If I use non-existence property on an json, it wont throw error. Due to this, sometimes we may end up deploying the code without realizing the issue. Is there a way to fail the build if the json structure does not match with the type defined ?

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} ListState
 * @property {Boolean} loading
 * @property {string} error
 * @property {FetchResponse} data
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} CreateFirmState
 * @property {Boolean} loading
 * @property {string} error
 * @property {*} data
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} UpdateFirmState
 * @property {Boolean} loading
 * @property {string} error
 * @property {*} data
 */

/*
* @type {UpdateFirmState}
*/
const myObject = 'hello'

// This above line should throw error because I'm defined myObject to be a string
```

3. I want to replace the existing vanilla js with the typescript, but not all the files completely. IS there a way to replce file one by one as we move forward or do we have to replace all the files?

Comment: Are you talking about the `JSON.parse` method in point 2?

Comment: I can answer point 3 definitely, you can use the `allowJs` option to migrate the project file by file: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/allowJs.html.

Comment: @Elias  No..I mean i fyou defined a variable to a string in the comment but define its value to be number, then it wont throw error.

Comment: Well then you're clearly doing something fishy (lol) and should stop doing that :,D